# broken python3 and pip on macos sonoma

Tags: homebrew, python

recently i tried to install a python package for example boto3 on my mac but i get this error

```
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
 ╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try brew install
xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
install.

If you wish to install a non-brew-packaged Python package,
create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip.

If you wish to install a non-brew packaged Python application,
it may be easiest to use pipx install xyz, which will manage a
virtual environment for you. Make sure you have pipx installed.
note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages. hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.
```

i just created another user on my mac to see if there is problem on that. i install brew and oh my zsh on that and had no problem there. what is wrong here?

the following is the content of my .zprofile

```
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"

export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
```